# passing the system symbols to char*

Tags: c++

I have changed my code, according to the reccommendations to my previous question. Now, i have the following code:

```
char* id = someFunction();      
if (strcmp(id,"0x01") == 0) {
    unsigned char cbuffer[]={0x01, 0x00};
    id=reinterpret_cast<char*>(cbuffer);
}
```

My question - is it the correct approach, to pass the `{0x01, 0x00}` to the id of type char*? And the second question is - how to free the id pointer after?

Comment: C does not have `reinterpret_cast` retagged to C++. Also, you never call `malloc()` or `new` so you do not need to deallocate anything explicitly.

Comment: You should explain better what you really are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unless `someFunction()` allocates the memory it returns a pointer to (which would be bad coding practice), your `id` points at some function-local memory that is no longer valid once the function returned.

Comment: You are initializing `cbuffer[]` with the integer values 1, 0. Calling `reinterpret_cast` is almost *always* not the correct way to do things, and not even available in C (which is probably why Als re-tagged your question as C++). If you want to convert the string returned by `someFunction` to an integer value, use `strtol()` or similar. Other than that, it is unclear what you want to achieve (as sth pointed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted is dangerous as you are passing a pointer to storage that is in automatic scope. The buffer will be trashed when it leaves scope (the scope of the if in this case).

Instead try something like this:

```
id = strdup((char*)cbuffer);
```

or even better you could use escape sequences and avoid having to specify the char values yourself:

```
id = strdup("\x01");
```

You can then free the memory used by this string by using `free`.

Comment: In the real world `malloc`ing for 2 bytes feels bad. But `id = malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); strncpy(id, "\x01", 2);` is the portable option.

Comment: If all `someFunction()` ever does is translate a single hex string to a number, you could have it return a pointer to a `static` internal buffer, which would make it non-threadsafe though. Or you could pass a pointer-to-buffer as parameter. Ah, choices, and one worse than the next. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to compare id to string value "0x01" or are you trying to compare the id value if it is char ASCII 0x01?

Also, how you free it depends on how you allocated `char*` returned by `someFunction()`? is this code pure C or is it C++? if `someFunction()` allocates using `new char[2]`, then you have to free it using `delete[]`. If you allocated using C style `malloc(sizeof(char)*2)`, then you have to do a `free(id)`.

Consider also that before you do `strdup`, as suggested in previous post, you have to free the original id. This is of course assuming, if by design, the pointer returned by `someFunction()` doesn't point to some global constant which is not supposed to be deallocated.

```
char* id = someFunction();      
if (strcmp(id,"0x01") == 0) { // no idea if this line make sense at all. 
    free(id); // or delete[] id; if id is allocated using new char[];
    static char[] cbuffer = {0x01, 0x00};
    id = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    strcpy(id, cbuffer);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that people have actually advised such a code here. If they did, they were reckless. **This is bad code**.

Chance your usage of `char*` to `std::string` and change the implementation of `someFunction` accordingly. However, this only helps to some extent because it’s unclear what you actually want to do here:

> is it the correct approach, to pass the {0x01, 0x00} to the id of type char*?

That makes no sense. What do you want to achieve? What do these values signify and why do you want to reinterpret them as a string? If you just want to obtain a string consisting of the char value 0x01, the following works:

```
std::string result = "\x01";
```